# In the usage string of my custom shell script, shall I also display --help and --version?

Tags: bash, shell-script, options, user-interface

I'm currently developing a shell script, called `up`, which shows a usage string on the commandline when called with `--help`. The output looks like this:

```
$ up --help
usage: up [-n levels][--help][--versions][basename]...
```

This looks okay but I'm wondering if I actually need to show the `--help` and `--version` options because they are a widely accepted standard and only seem to add noise to the usage string.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is entirely up to you but most programs do someting like this

```
program --help

Usage: program [<options>][<arguments> ...]

Options:
--help         show this message, then exit
--something    after some spaces for alignment, an explenation follows.
```

You should check out [getopt](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt) which most programs (this is also available in programming languages) and scripts use. This way people using your script will not get confused.

Finally, you should add *all* your options even if they seem trivial to you to be complete. So, I would add both --help and --version in the Options section of the usage.

Comment: +1 for usage consistency across different tools (there seem to be several [getopt(s)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/402410/993018), btw)

Comment: +1 most of the gnu tools conform to @silverrocker's style too. It's always nice when scripts/commands have a similar look and feel when looking at their usage. Just look at how `ls --help` and `du --help` present their usage info and follow their lead.

Comment: The `getopt` **command** is **not** in the standard Unix toolchest. There exist several differing implementations with different interfaces. `getopts` is standard, but the standard doesn't cover GNU-style long options. There's a getopts_long.sh [there](http://stchaz.free.fr/getopts_long.sh) for a POSIX implementation as a shell function.

Comment: +1 This looks like an awesome solution. Is this somewhere documented? I often have a hard time finding resources which tell you how something like this should be implemented (so that it will be consistent across different tools).

Comment: I've been in the same position not knowing how I should do things properly. I have read the Gnu Coding Standard (http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html) which answers some of the questions you might have about standardization and consistency. The relevant section for arguments is "Standards for Command Line Interfaces".